# How can 100Base-T achieve 100 meter distance at 125Mhz clock?

Tags: networking

I admit I have some large holes in my understanding of this topic, but it seems like you run into physical limitations of the speed of light.

If the speed of electricity through copper is about 280,000,000 meters per second, and the clock on the ethernet card is running at 125Mhz (found this online, not sure if this is the right speed), the signal should only be able to travel about

```
280,000,000 * (1/125,000,000) = ~2.24 meters
```

before the next clock cycle starts. Assuming only 1 bit can be on a wire at a time (possibly a bad assumption), how is 100 meters possible?

Comment: There are two bad assumptions: you assume that the sender must wait for the data to reach the receiver, and you assume that one bit is present on the wire at any time. Both are wrong. If you explain a bit why you think so, helping you understanding what is really going on will be simpler

Comment: @VladimirCravero I thought since the signal is essentially a difference in voltage, when you change the voltage, the signal that's midway across the wire gets clobbered? As to the one bit on the wire assumption, I'm guessing there are ways to combine several bits into one 'pulse' if you use more than 2 voltage levels to represent values. But still, it's one signal which I thought would be clobbered the same way as a single bit.

Comment: The signal is not a difference in voltages, it is an electromagnetic wave. Light (=EM wave) propagates in air, or in glass, which can be turned into fibres. Depending on the wavelength (=frequency), different media must be used to transmit these waves. Vacuum can propagate anything, glass can transmit the frequencies which makes visible light, metals can only transmit low frequency signals, up to a few terahertz.

Comment: @TEMLIB Sorry, I may be mixing terms, or misunderstanding completely. As I understand, a voltage difference on both ends of the wire induces a current to flow from one end to the other. So if you alternate the voltage back and forth quickly before the current has time to flow completely across the wire, I'd assume on the receiving end, rather than seeing the previous current level, followed by the new current level, you'd maybe see the average of the two? Or would you actually see both, one after the other?

Comment: The first part of [this video](https://youtu.be/jUQkG1A0_Sk) gives a good visualization of how pulses propagate independently. Look especially at the section starting at 2:30, where they show two pulses being sent from one end and arriving safely at the other, even though they're much shorter than the "wire".

Comment: Think of the motions of the bits as like waves in a pond, yes changing bits changes the flow of current, but these changes can only propagate at some fraction of light speed (I think 2/3rds for properly terminated transmission lines). So in long runs, any change at one end takes time to move down the line and as each change (or bit) moves with an equal speed, they can never catch up to each other.

Comment: The actual distance limits come from attenuation and noise pickup, and in the days of shared cabling, the *time allowances* built into the protocol.  When there were multiple units on the wire, the protocol had to (crudely speaking) enforce certain wait-before-talk times to see if a signal from anyone else might be travelling on the wire, and these times were calculated from a maximum cable length and the speed of light in cable, which is on the order of 70% of what it is in free space.  Better cable could help with attenuation, but only a split to logical segments helps with time allowances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question:

```
the signal should only be able to travel about 280,000,000 * (1/125,000,000)
 =~2.24 meters before the next clock cycle starts.
```

From one of your comments:

```
"I thought since the signal is essentially a difference in voltage, when you
change the voltage, the signal that's midway across the wire gets clobbered?"
```

You have provided the answer yourself: the next bit that is put on the line won't be able to clobber the bit that is halfway because that next bit can travel only at a fixed speed, and the bit that is halfway travels at the same speed. They will never meet (except at the far end, if it not properly terminated, but that's a different story).

If you want to visualise this, take a long rope in one hand , the other end of the rope fixed. Now you can wave your end of the rope to cause a wave in the rope to travel from your hand to the other end. For a long rope, there can be miltiple waves all traveling towards the other (fixed) end, without overtaling each other.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense, I think I was mixing up a conceptual model of current appearing to travel instantaneously, when it actually just happens really fast.

Comment: That's the trouble with analogies: you must know under which restrictions you can use them. In this case you were mixing two abstraction, one of which (instantaneous current/voltage relation) was outside its validity domain because you were looking at a very fast fenomenon. Don't worry, knowing when an abstraction can be applied is one of the fundamental and most challenging aspects of all sciences :)